# Overflow of unsigned integers

Tags: go

[Go spec say](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Integer_overflow) on unsigned integer overflow:

> For unsigned integer values, the operations +, -, *, and << are
>   computed modulo 2n, where n is the bit width of the unsigned integer's
>   type. Loosely speaking, these unsigned integer  operations discard high
>   bits upon overflow, and **programs may rely on ''wrap around''**.

I try to test it, but get inconsistent result - http://play.golang.org/p/sJxtSHbigT:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("test")
    var num uint32 = 1 << 35
}
```

This give error:

```
prog.go:7: constant 34359738368 overflows uint32
 [process exited with non-zero status]
```

But according to spec should be no error but rather I should seen 0.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The specification you quote refers specifically to the results of "the operations +, -, *, and <<". You're trying to define a constant, not looking at the result of one of those operations.

You also can't use those over-sized values for the input of those operations. The compiler won't wrap any values for you; that's just the runtime behaviour of those operations.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var num uint32 = 1 + 1 << 35
    fmt.Printf("num = %v\n", num)
}
```

```
prog.go:6: constant 34359738369 overflows uint32
 [process exited with non-zero status]
```

---

Here's an interesting example.

```
var num uint32 = (1 << 31) + (1 << 31)
fmt.Printf("num = %v\n", num)
```

```
prog.go:6: constant 4294967296 overflows uint32
 [process exited with non-zero status]
```

In this case, the compiler attempts to evaluate `(1 << 31) + (1 << 31)` at compile-time, producing the constant value `4294967296`, which is too large to fit.

```
var num uint32 = (1 << 31)
num += (1 << 31)
fmt.Printf("num = %v\n", num)
```

```
num = 0
```

In this case, the addition is performed at run-time, and the value wraps around as you'd expect.

Answer (score 3):

That's because `1 << 35` is an untyped constant expression (it only involves numerical constants). It doesn't become an `uint32` until you assign it. Go prohibits you to assign to a variable a constant expression that would overflow it as stuff like that is almost certainly unintentional.